# Editing ACH info for recurring contributions - iATS

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, iats

CiviCRM 4.6.14, Drupal 7.43, iATS Payments extension 1.5.3

Should admins be able to edit ACH info (e.g., change the routing and account number) for recurring contributions?  This is available for recurring contributions paid by credit card (view, edit, and process links are available), but not for recurring contributions paid by ACH (only view links are available).  Is this by design or is there possibly another issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - you can not Edit ACHEFT Card on File via the CiviCRM interface: (left: ACH/EFT; right is Credit Card):

[image]

To Edit the Routing + Account Number associated with the ACHEFT recurring series go to iATSpayments.com -> Virtual Terminal -> Customer Database -> Find the record -> hit Edit -> and make Edits to the Payment Information section. This will change the Account Number (or Credit Card) that is attached to the token that is already associated in CiviCRM with the recurring series; Remember to leave your Recurring Payment Settings to OFF here -> otherwise your donor/member will be processed twice -> once triggered from CiviCRM and once triggered from iATSPayments.com

Comment: Definitely the correct answer for now. I believe this is the first time anyone has asked for the card on file functions for ACHEFT, it's not specifically excluded by design, just not yet implemented (the fields and logic of ACH recurring contribution 'card on file' are different from credit cards). Feel free to add it to our issues list.